# Drawing Square field for snake using source code

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a square field using this code. but somehow it ended up wrong. could anyone help me point out my mistakes? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as it my first time learning C. Here is the code

```
int i,j;

const int width = 30;

const int height = 30;

int main()
{  
  for(int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++){
      printf("#");
  }

  for(int i = 0;i < height; i++){    
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
      if(j == 0){  printf("#")  }
      if(j == 0){  printf(" ");  }
      if(j == width - 1){  printf("#");  }
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++){
    printf("#"); 
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong

Comment: _But somehow it ended up wrong._ What is your desired output and what went wrong? Though, your code won't compile (e.g. missing `;` within your first `if`). In addition, this double `if (j == 0)` looks wired.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that. it printed out a c shaped field rather than a square field.

Comment: i don't know how to print multiple time using the same condition. That's why i used double if(j == 0).

Comment: Just use if () { } else if () {} else if () {} construction. Otherwise you'll get more symbols printed than squares on your field.

Comment: i really wanna cry now, thank you guys for all the answer. finally got my square ^^

Comment: Not an answer, but the `printf` function has a **width** field for each format specifier, including string arguments, and may take a variable value.  This means you could eliminate the inner loop with the line: `printf("#%*s#\n",width,""); //Print #, the empty string will be padded with width blank spaces, another # and end with new-line.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you want something more like

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < width + 2; j++){ //Note width + 2, to match your top line
    if (j == 0){ printf("#"); } // print near border
    else if (j == (width + 1)){ printf("#"); } // print far border
    else { printf(" "); } // when it's  not a far border or near border, print an empty space
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

You shouldn't have to print "#" *and* " " for the near border, just "#", and you then print " " for all of the spaces inside the square. Finally for the far edge you print "#" again.

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in your second if statement. You want to print " " when j ist not 0 or width-1

```
if(j == 0 || j == width - 1){  
    printf("#") ;
} else {
    printf(" ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The second if(j == 0) is at fault. Remove it and you'll get the square you desire.